# Ruby on Rails - Javascripts Folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How do I get rails to generate the default prototype javascript files in my `public/javascripts` folder?  I have deleted them after experimenting with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resurrect them from a previous commit. You're using git right?

```
git reflog # find how many commits back your JS is. Let's assume 4.
git checkout master~4 public/javascripts
```

Comment: Thought there might have been a way with rails.  But thanks I got them back using git.

Comment: Yeah I looked for a rails way. Looks like there's only a generator for the jquery javascripts using the `jquery-rails` gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a built-in way, but you could get them back out of your source repo, if you're using one, or generate a new rails project (being sure to use the same version of rails) and copy them over.